# The ~ prefix in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been learning core audio on the iPhone, and when looking through Apple's sample code I found this:

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#include "CAStreamBasicDescription.h"
#include "CAXException.h"

#define kNumberBuffers 3

class AQPlayer
    {
    public:
        AQPlayer();
        ~AQPlayer();

        OSStatus                        StartQueue(BOOL inResume);
        OSStatus                        StopQueue();        
        OSStatus                        PauseQueue();

        AudioQueueRef                   Queue()                 { return mQueue;}
        CAStreamBasicDescription        DataFormat() const      { return mDataFormat; }     
        Boolean                         IsRunning() const       { return (mIsRunning) ? true : false; }
        Boolean                         IsInitialized() const   { return mIsInitialized; }      
        CFStringRef                     GetFilePath() const     { return (mFilePath) ? mFilePath : CFSTR(""); }
        Boolean                         IsLooping() const       { return mIsLooping; }

        void SetLooping(Boolean inIsLooping)    { mIsLooping = inIsLooping; }
        void CreateQueueForFile(CFStringRef inFilePath);
        void DisposeQueue(Boolean inDisposeFile);   

    private:
        UInt32                          GetNumPacketsToRead()               { return mNumPacketsToRead; }
        SInt64                          GetCurrentPacket()                  { return mCurrentPacket; }
        AudioFileID                     GetAudioFileID()                    { return mAudioFile; }
        void                            SetCurrentPacket(SInt64 inPacket)   { mCurrentPacket = inPacket; }

        void                            SetupNewQueue();

        AudioQueueRef                   mQueue;
        AudioQueueBufferRef             mBuffers[kNumberBuffers];
        AudioFileID                     mAudioFile;
        CFStringRef                     mFilePath;
        CAStreamBasicDescription        mDataFormat;
        Boolean                         mIsInitialized;
        UInt32                          mNumPacketsToRead;
        SInt64                          mCurrentPacket;
        UInt32                          mIsRunning;
        Boolean                         mIsDone;
        Boolean                         mIsLooping;

        static void isRunningProc(      void *              inUserData,
                                        AudioQueueRef           inAQ,
                                        AudioQueuePropertyID    inID);

        static void AQBufferCallback(   void *                  inUserData,
                                        AudioQueueRef           inAQ,
                                        AudioQueueBufferRef     inCompleteAQBuffer); 

        void CalculateBytesForTime(     CAStreamBasicDescription & inDesc, 
                                        UInt32 inMaxPacketSize, 
                                        Float64 inSeconds, 
                                        UInt32 *outBufferSize, 
                                        UInt32 *outNumPackets);                                                                     
    };
```

Does anyone know what this line does: `~AQPlayer();`
I haven't seen the symbol `~` used before.

Comment: It that ObjC? It looks like C++... but does Apple even support C++?

Comment: @delnan: Yes, some Apple frameworks are C++ based.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a `c` related. It looks like `c++` in which case the `~` is the `desctructor` for the class. You might want to read about destructors in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html)

Comment: The question is actually Objective C as pointed out by the tags. But you are correct in that this doesn't apply to C.

Comment: Matthew: thanks for that. I didn't realize it was for an IPhone.

Comment: @user The deconstructor is called just before the object is destroyed in memory. It's supposed to be for if the object needs to do any cleanup behind itself. On a PC app, typical uses might be to delete a temporary file, or that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a C++ class, not an Objective-C class. The `~` symbol is used to declare or define a destructor method, a method that is automatically called when an instance's lifetime ends. The destructor method of a C++ class is used in the same way that a `dealloc` method is used in Objective-C classes (to clean up resources, and so on). The difference is that in Objective-C, `dealloc` is not invoked until it has no owners (i.e. all owners have relinquished their ownership by sending `release`).

If you wish to know what this code does, perhaps ask a C++ crowd, although, from a quick glance, it looks like an audio player utilising Apple's [AudioToolbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAAudioTooboxRef/_index.html) framework.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like C++ to me. It is supported on iOS, so that's why you’re seeing it.

Comment: C++ is supported in iOS.  But the question is about Objective C, not iOS.  This ~ is in an include file that can be imported into Objective C source code (.m files), not C++ or Objective C++ (.mm files) source code.  Where is this documented as legal?

Answer (score 0):

That is c++ code, to develop with these from Objective-C you'd use Objective-C++.  Files with .mm are Obj-c++ and .m are just standard obj-c.

Answer (score -2):

thats the destructor. in C++ the destructors are as this, while this code looks more like C++, in objective C you can write the destructor with "~"

Comment: C is not object-oriented. Thus, there are no classes. Thus, no objects. Thus, there are no destructors. Period.